# Append string to UserAgent on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent, kiosk-mode

I want to append a string to the UserAgent of a PC running Chrome, and not change the UserAgent altogether because I still want the browser to be recognized as the correct Chrome version. I could just use a UserAgent switcher and enter in the current UserAgent but then it wouldn't be correct after a few updates. The website contains some WebRTC elements so it's imperative that the correct version of Chrome is detected.

The reason is this, we have developed a website for an apartment complex of elderly people. They can use it at home, but the owner of the complex has also put two all-in-one PCs in the lobby for people without PCs to use.

Those PCs run Chrome in kiosk mode, and I need to be able to detect visits coming from those PCs. Outgoing links have to be opened in an iframe (since they can't open/close tabs) and I run some javascript that automatically logs people out after 5 min. But all that only has to run on those 2 specific PCs, I don't want people to get logged out at home.

I tried detecting it simply by checking the screen height like so:

```
if (screen.availHeight || screen.height-30) <= window.innerHeight) {
    // code
}
```

But that breaks when people use Ctrl-+ to zoom in. The `window.innerHeight` will change and the if statement won't work. Any other methods of detecting a fullscreen website didn't work, or only detect if the browser supports fullscreen.

Is there a plugin/method of appending a string to the UserAgent so I can check for it using Javascript? Or any other way of detecting Chrome in kiosk mode? I don't want to add a query to the url, that's technically impossible for our website.

Comment: Cookies / localStorage, maybe? An extension can be used to persist those. Relying on UserAgent seems like a weird roundabout approach.

Comment: And if you process this client-side and not server-side, why not use `externally_connectable`?

Comment: I'm not sure what `externally_connectable` is. I'm not making a Chrome extension, I'm a website builder and the client just wants this feature for those specific 2 PCs. I was looking for an extension to persist a cookie but can't find anything, any suggestions? I don't want to have to go back there every 2 months to set a new cookie.

Comment: You kinda did put a Chrome extensions _development_ tag here.. Anyway, why not the most obvious solution: IPs?

Comment: My bad, I thought it was for getting suggestions on existing Chrome extensions, I've removed the tag. IPs won't work because (at least in my country) static IPs are impossible to get. Even companies can't get them from ISPs anymore.

Comment: It really might be easier if you develop a simple extension for this use case, though.. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage for what I mentioned. If you're really looking for a ready solution, [softwarerecs.se] or [su] may be a better place.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really my field of expertise. The reason why I went with UserAgent is because I once developed a simple WebView Android app, and in there I could append a string to the UserAgent for easy recognition. It persists and is foolproof. There should be some way of doing it right?

Comment: From an _extension_, yes. Honestly, you can write an extension to do what you want in many possible ways in a day, if you have JS experience at all.

Comment: I'll do some more research, thanks for all the help!